# Adding class to div user has just scrolled to

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to add a class to a div that the user has scrolled to, but for some reason no matter what I write the div doesn't open.

I am using location.hash == "" to check whether or not a certain string is in the url which is fine and then scrolling to that div. Once it has scrolled to that div I want to remove the hide class and add the show class (which will show the div) but I can't get it to work.

It's probably really simple but I can't achieve the right effect.

Here is my code:

```
if(window.location.hash == 'data-sheets') {
    $.scrollTo('.Data-Sheets', 0, { offset:-1 } , { easing:'elasout' }); 
    $(".Data-Sheets .expand2").removeClass("hide");
    $(".Data-Sheets .expand2").addClass("show");
}
```

Comment: Depending on what the classes consist of, you could call `.hide()` / `.show()` instead of applying classes (not directly related to the Q)

Comment: .hide is just hiding the div and .show will display the div. I have applied .hide to all divs by default because I don't want to display them when the page loads. They should display when the user scrolls to a certain div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this for anyone else trying to achieve the same thing as me.

I didn't realise that I was missing the hash in my if statement, by adding it it solved my problem and the classes were being added/removed properly.

Here is my final code:

```
if(window.location.hash == '#data-sheets') {
    $.scrollTo('.Data-Sheets', 0, { offset:-1 } , { easing:'elasout' });
    $('.Data-Sheets .expand2').removeClass('hide');
    $('.Data-Sheets .expand2').addClass('show');    
return false;
}
```

I also added this function to check whether or not the hash has been changed because I needed to flick between different links, it 'hides' all the divs by default because I didn't want to show them and then removed the 'show' class and then it scrolls to the right point.

```
function locationHashChanged() {

   if(location.hash == '#data-sheets') {
       $.scrollTo('.Data-Sheets', 0, { offset:-1 } , { easing:'elasout' });
       $('.expand2.show').addClass('hide');
       $('.expand2.show').removeClass('show');
       $('.Data-Sheets .expand2').addClass('show');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### A Pure CSS Solution

Depending on what you're wanting to achieve, you could make use of CSS's [`:target` pseudo-class selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#target-pseudo).

> Some URIs refer to a location within a resource. This kind of URI ends with a "number sign" (#) followed by an anchor identifier (called the fragment identifier).
>
> URIs with fragment identifiers link to a certain element within the document, known as the target element. For instance, here is a URI pointing to an anchor named section_2 in an HTML document:
>
> `http://example.com/html/top.html#section_2`
>
> A target element can be represented by the :target pseudo-class. If the document's URI has no fragment identifier, then the document has no target element.

For example:

```css
.Data-Sheets .expand2 {
  display: none;
}

.Data-Sheets .expand2:target {
  display: block;
}
```

Here's a JSBin demo of this in action, using the following markup:

```
<div class="Data-Sheets">
  <p class="expand2" id="foo">I should be visible when #foo is added to the URL.</p>
  <p class="expand2" id="bar">I should be visible when #bar is added to the URL.</p>
</div>
```

1. With no target specified: http://jsbin.com/qowurijavi/1
2. With `#foo` specified: http://jsbin.com/qowurijavi/1/#foo
3. With `#bar` specified: http://jsbin.com/qowurijavi/1/#bar

Provided your browser handles the `:target` pseudo-class, in the first example both `p` elements should be hidden; in the second you should see the first `p` element should be visible, but not the second; and in the third the second `p` element should be visible, but not the first.

Comment: I tried your solution @JamesDonnelly but it didn't work. Sorry

Comment: I added the CSS as you suggested and I made sure my divs had the right class/ID but when i scrolled to that div it didn't open. Your suggestion is good and I saw your links it does work. Maybe I am missing something in my code. I would prefer to use a JS method though.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
function scrollToDiv(id) {
    var id = $("#"+id);
    if( id.position().top + $(window).height() - $(window).scrollTop() > 0 )
        id.addClass("focus");
    else
        id.removeClass("focus");     
}
```

### Usage:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    scrollToDiv("mydiv");
});
```

### Fiddle:

Here's a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Marventus/60o17eku/) for reference.